# HTML5 drag and drop image offset on drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a `draggable="true"` element which I am dropping into a drop zone. The event gives me back a few properties which I can use to determine it's position and create a new element where it got dropped.

It seems to only give the mouse position. But it doesn't seem to contain the offset of where the image was in relation to the mouse.

**Where would I get that information?**

[image: Image Offset Example]

A picture to help explain, the mouse is at the yellow dot. The drop event returns `event.x` and `event.y` where the mouse is.... But I need to know where the blue dot is, or the offset (red lines)

Comment: there is a related set of coords on the image onmousedown or maybe ondragstart, something like that. anyway, you need to remember those until the drag is done, it's simple addition and subtraction from there...

Comment: Do you know the parameter names for the coords?

Comment: well, different ones do different things, some are relative to window, some to the container, some on the element itself. i would just inspect a few on the browsers i need to support until i found something that worked with my code. sorry i don't have a concrete answer, but i've seen about a dozen in my days...

Answer (score 0):

There are offsetX and offsetY properties in html5 native DragEvent.

For example in React you can get these values through native

```
function onDragStart(event: React.DragEvent) {
    console.log(event.nativeEvent.offsetX)
    console.log(event.nativeEvent.offsetY)
}
```